# for..in statement not supported for XML DOM childNodes in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

We're developing a javascript-based GIS application and everything was going fine until someone decided to fire up IE9 and gave it a spin over there too. As you have probably already guessed, the app broke down.

Turned out that for some inexplicable reason `for..in` loop is unable to iterate over `childNodes`:

```
var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
xmldoc.loadXML("<i18n><item>one</item><item>two</item></i18n>");

var currentItem = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("i18n")[0].firstChild;

while (currentItem) {
    if (currentItem.nodeType == 1) {
        for (var i in currentItem.childNodes) {
            console.log(currentItem.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    currentItem = currentItem.nextSibling;
}
```

However, when the internal `for` loop in above code is replaced with

```
for (var j = 0; j < currentItem.childNodes.length; j++) {
    console.log(currentItem.childNodes[j]);
}
```

everything works as expected - it walks the child nodes without any issues.

Although I discovered a workaround, the issue still annoys me as it is not clear why it happens. MSDN documentation both for [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [for..in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/55wb2d34%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) mentions nothing.

Is this a bug or another case of poorly-documented oddness that IE is famous of?

Comment: Whether or not there's a reason, you shouldn't be using a `for...in` loop to iterate over an array or array-like object anyways

Comment: The `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList object, which is **not** an Array instance. Internet Explorer does not consider the numeric indexes to be properties of NodeList objects (which is not unreasonable).

Comment: @Pointy The OP isn't iterating over the result of `getElementsByTagName()`; they're iterating over `.childNodes`; doesn't seem to matter, they both return a `NodeList` as you say. And according to this jsFiddle, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/QZ37D/ . Of course, this is with the DOM and not an XML Document, so is there a difference?

Comment: @Ian oh you're right; duhh. Well still, the "childNodes" value is a NodeList too I think.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. That didn't change anything, I was just saying. But like I show in the fiddle, a normal `.childNodes` access in the DOM allows for (improperly) looping with `for...in`. The OP seems to want to know why it doesn't work for XML documents

Comment: Just to be clear here, your question doesn't concern an "IE9 XML DOM object", it's instead about an IE6-era MSXML ActiveX object.

Comment: @EricLaw - Not necessarily. If that were the case then the underlying MSXML library should suffer from same issues in VB, C# and C/C++ also but that is not possible as `for..in` statement is unique to JS. According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx), `loadXML` "*creates a DOMDocument object*". In that sense, it's not about MSXML but about implementation details of the W3C DOM interface specification Esailija mentions in his answer. I appreciate your suggestion but I think it's not entirely accurate.

Comment: Saul: MSXML is an ActiveX object. It's not a part of IE. If you think I'm mistaken, please do a quick Google for me. thanks.

Comment: @EricLaw - According to [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238/en-us), "*The Microsoft XML parser is a Component Object Model (COM) implementation of the W3C DOM model.*" but you are right in that the issue is related to ActiveX. What I meant was that the focus of the question was on behavior of DOM objects. However its causes are another topic and that information belongs to the answers section - you are more than welcome to write one. The question is fine just as it is.

Comment: The problem with the question is that IE9 also has a native XML DOM which isn't the same as the MSXML version. If you're happy with your question and don't want an adjustment from someone who worked on the IE engineering team for *eight years*, that's your call.

Comment: @EricLaw - I already know IE9 has a native XML DOM also, I also know now that its behavior is different from DOM objects originating from ActiveX and I respect your experience but as I said, there is no point in making a question into an answer also. This is not how Stack Overflow works. If you have the time to write a good answer rather than a comment, you'd receive my upvote and probably the accepted answer status too as you obviously have much deeper knowledge on this topic than any other previous poster. I hope you understand where I am coming from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a bug since [DOM spec doesn't define](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) that there should be numeric properties, just the `item` method which `[]` desugars to.

Simply don't use `for..in`.

Comment: I suppose there is a fair amount of confusion about this. Newer IE-s and other modern browsers support NodeList `for..in` without any issues and as a bonus, Microsoft's own documentation has an example that "*illustrates the use of the for ... in statement to iterate though an Array object that has expando properties.*".

Comment: @Saul `NodeList` is not an `Array`. `Array` is a JS object while `NodeList` is a host object which are from completely different worlds. What IE9 is doing is overly liberal interpretation of the spec, it is completely valid for `for..in` to work on XML `.childNodes` but not on HTML `.childNodes`.

Comment: Aah.. there, that's it - I was operating under an implicit assumption that NodeList is basically the same as Array which it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays. Arrays should always be iterated with a `for()` loop. Only non-array objects should use `for...in`.

If you *must* use a `for..in` here, you should filter the loop using `.hasOwnProperty()` to prevent unwanted iterations on properties that belong to the array prototype rather than the array itself.

This point applies to *all* `for..in` loops: to ensure your code is robust, you should get into the habit of always filtering them with `.hasOwnProperty()`, even on plain objects, but especially on arrays, since we already know they contain additional properties.

[See here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/) for more on this point.

Comment: Well to be fair, prop checks would eliminate the sole reason people used for..in for arrays in the first place: typing convenience. Why not rather introduce them to the wonders of text editor/IDE macros?

Comment: Well.. the irony is that Microsoft's own `for..in` [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/55wb2d34%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) has dedicated a significant chunk of page space for an example captioned as "*This example illustrates the use of the for ... in statement to iterate though an Array object that has expando properties.*". Go figure, then.

Comment: @Saul: yes, that's a little unfortunate, isn't is. heh.

Comment: @Esailija - yes, you're right; this whole issue means that there's really no point in using `for..in` for arrays.